# Can I do this in Java?

Tags: java, class, dynamic

Is there a way of doing this in Java?

```
class A { ... }
class B { ... }

void method()
{
 Class[] array = {A,B,A,A};
 int i = 2;
 Object object = new array[i]();
}
```

and no, I don't want to use any ifs or switches like below

```
if(i==0) object = new A();
else if(i==1) object = new B();
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to do something like this:

```
class A { ... }
class B { ... }
void method(){
    Class[] array = {A.class, B.class, A.class, A.class};
    int i = 2;
    Object object = array[i].newInstance();
}
```

The class must have a default constructor (one with no arguments) in order for `newInstance()` to work.

Comment: For some reason, newInstance() throws an InstantiationException

Comment: [Class.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance())

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the classes you could put istances of the corresponding classes directly in the array without the need to reinstantiate them.

```
class A {
    A(){...} 
}
class B { 
    B(){...}
}

void method()
{
     Object[] array = {new A(), new B(), new A(), new A()};
     int i = 2;
     Object object = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Class[] classes = {A.class, B.class, A.class, A.class};
int i = 2;
Object obj = classes[i].newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java reflection to do this.  With Java reflection you can get the 'Class' identity and then get the Constructor, then new instance with it.  You can check it out from 
[Java Reflection Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html)!